# Moment generating function and independence

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, independence, moment-generating-functions

I am interested on the proof of the following result:

> If $X=(X_1,\ldots,X_n)$ is a random vector, then $M_X(t_1,\ldots,t_n)=M_{X_{1}}(t_1)\cdots M_{X_{n}}(t_n)$ for all $(t_1,\ldots,t_n)$ implies that $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ are independent.

I have been searching for a proof on the Internet, and found this one [here](https://books.google.ca/books?id=zF1kkWU_fmQC&pg=PA242&dq=moment+generating+function+independent+if+and+only+if&hl=en&sa=X&ei=h7J5UoaRNuGfyQGQtIGACw#v=onepage&q=moment%20generating%20function%20independent%20if%20and%20only%20if&f=false).

My doubt relies on the proof of P2. More concretely, I do not understand the statement "$M_X$ is equal to the moment generating function of a vector whose components $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ are independent". How do you know that vector exists? If you want to prove that $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ are precisely independent, how can you construct a vector whose components $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ are independent?

Comment: It is a general fact that given some distributions, there exist a random vector whose entries are independent and have these distributions. For an explicit construction, assume that $X_i:(\Omega_i,P_i)\to E_i$ has the desired marginal and consider $\Omega=\prod\limits_i\Omega_i$, $P=\bigotimes\limits_iP_i$, $E=\prod\limits_iE_i$, and $X:(\Omega,P)\to E$ defined by $$X(\omega_1,\omega_2,\ldots,\omega_n)=(X_1(\omega_1),X_2(\omega_2),\ldots,X_n(\omega_n))$$

Comment: @Did Thank you for your comment. Could you suggest any book or notes where I could study about that result and the corresponding proofs?